# How to fix SQL Injection Issue of truncation of table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection, secure-coding

Below is the line of code where I truncate table records. The table value is coming from the front end. In my Veracode scan, it is showing SQL injection. How can I avoid this? I cannot create a stored procedure as the connection string is dynamic where I need to truncate this table. Is there another approach?

```
SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.Transaction = transaction;
cmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE " + tablename;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: you can mark as false positive. But I agree, this is a bad move. Why can't you create procedure(s)?

Comment: how many tables could possibly be sent to this code?  I'd say put the list of possible tables into an array or hashset and have your code make sure the passed in value of "tablename" is in there.  Then use the value from the array instead of the passed in value.

Comment: It's not exactly a false positive. Yet. You need to make sure you're properly escaping the name, first.

Comment: or use an enumerated type or const string for "tablename" instead of a regular string

Comment: string sqlStatement = string.Format("TRUNCATE TABLE [{0}]", tableName);

Comment: @TS as I said the connection string is dynamic  where I need to truncate the table , we are framing the connection string value from the DB Value which is coming from front end  and executing this truncate statement in that connection string context ,  how sp will help and where we put that sp

Comment: just a side note... i have been coding a long time using sql and have never had a need for application code (especially multi-tier!) to truncate a table so you may want to reconsider your design.  Unless you're writing a front-end to a database administration tool, I'm thinking there's a better way

Comment: @JoelFan I understand joe , its not designed by me and its very old code ,I just got the task to fix these issues so just wanted an efficient help if we can do anything without redesigning whole architecture

Comment: @SarveshGupta Every DB will have to contain this SP, where you pass table mane and execute dynamic code. It doesn't matter where you get connection from.

Answer (score 5):

You need dynamic sql:

```
string sql = @"
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(150); 
    SELECT @SQL = 'truncate table ' + quotename(table_name) + ';'
        FROM information_schema.tables 
        WHERE table_name = @table;
    EXEC(@SQL);";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@table", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = tablename;
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This is one of very few times dynamic SQL makes things *more* secure, rather than less. Even better, if you also maintain a special table in this database listing other tables users are allowed to truncate, and use that rather than information_schema to validate the name. The idea of letting users just truncate *anything* is kind of scary.

Comment: it won't  create sql injection flaw ?? as tablename is coming from front end

Comment: @SarveshGupta No it will not since that table name is parameterized here

Comment: @SarveshGupta This cycles the input through the database in a safe-ish way to be sure you have a valid table name. There's the still the question of why you would allow **any** table name to be selected and completely truncated.

Comment: @SarveshGupta Added more code for context. You can see now where the table is passed in as a safe parameter value.

Comment: @Rahul parameterisation is **not** making it magically safe here. It is the other steps

Comment: No amount of parameterization will matter with dynamic SQL if it's not properly escaped. That's what `QUOTENAME` is doing there. It all hinges on that.

Comment: @madreflection Also that I pulled the table name from the database. If the user enters something that's not a real table, there's nothing to quote. The two put together mean you at least get a single valid sql statement that does exactly what you'd expect. If it were me, though, I'd also have a special table in that database which lists a specific set of other tables users are allowed to truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Parametrized or not, you can make it only a little more secured in this case. Never totally secured. For this you need

> create table `TruncMapping` in DB where you store
>   `id guid`
>   `statement varchar(300)`
>   your data will look like
>   `SOME-GUID-XXX-YYY, 'TRUNCATE TABLE TBL1'`

- In your front end use a `listbox` or `combobox` with text/value like `"Customer Data"/"SOME-GUID-XXX-YYY"`
- In your code use `ExecuteScalar` to execute `Select statement from TruncMapping where id = @1` , where `id` will be parameterized GUID from combo value
- Execute your truncate command using `ExecuteNonQuery` as you do now but with a retrieved string from previous call.

Your scan tool will most likely choke. If it is still thinking code is unsafe, you can safely point this as false positive because what you execute is coming from your secured DB. Potential attacker has no way to sabotage your "non-tuncatable tables" because they are not listed in `TruncMapping` tables.

You've just created multi-layered defense against sql injection.

Answer (score -1):

here is one way to hide it from scanning tools

```cs
private const string _sql = "VFJVTkNBVEUgVEFCTEU=";
. . . . 

var temp = new { t = tablename };
cmd.CommandText = 
    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(_sql)) + temp.t.PadLeft(temp.t.Length + 1);
```

security by obscurity

Comment: Isn't this using obscurity to defeat a totally legitimate security concern being found by code analysis?

Comment: @MartinSmith you parametrize it or not, if you get something out of text box and concatenate to "Truncate Table", this is not secured. What is more secured, it is if control is a combo, or list box, if it is checked against table list, etc. Here we are dealing strictly with defeating a scanning tool

Comment: Why would you be trying to "defeat" a scanning tool that you run yourself? Don't run static code analysis if you don't think it is worthwhile , or if you have evaluated it in context and found it safe use whatever method that uses to flag as safe. Making the code highly obfuscated so no one can see what it does is not a good solution

Comment: @MartinSmith Lets talk about current situation. The only more or less secured way to do it is when you get a List with some ID in the front end, pass it to back end and check against, lets say, a table. Not information schema table but a custom table which holds this id and actual tuncate statement. And preferably, this Id will be some Guid. 
Now, the scan tools will complain about all these things bur you need this, period. These tools complain that your variable called `password` or `pwd`. So yea, we call these `p_zz4rd` or something like that, just for tool to stop whining